# EF Code First, two navigation properties to same object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using EF Code First to query and create a database. One of my entities (relationship) has two navigation properties to the same entity (activity). My problem is that if I use EF to create the database schema it will create four foreign key columns and constraints instead of two.

Here are the relevant code parts:

activity class:

```
public class Activity {
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Successors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Predecessors { get; set; }
}
```

relationship class:

```
public class Relationship {
    public virtual Activity Activity1 { get; set; }
    public int Activity1_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity2 { get; set; }
    public int Activity2_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship mapping class:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Activity1)
  .WithMany(t => t.Predecessors)
  .HasForeignKey(m => m.Activity1_ID)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
this.HasRequired(t => t.Activity2)
  .WithMany(t => t.Successors)
  .HasForeignKey(m => m.Activity2_ID)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Database structure:
[image]

Is there a way to prevent the creation of the last two columns?

Comment: It seems that you are not adding the mapping class to the context. Show the code of your context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should create you only 2 foreign key columns.

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Successors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Predecessors { get; set; }
}
public class Relationship
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual Activity Activity1 { get; set; }
    public int Activity1_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity2 { get; set; }
    public int Activity2_ID { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext class where i am specifying the relationship/FK nature on my `OnModelCreating`.

```
public class MyDb: DbContext
{
    public MyDb():base("EfDbContext")
    {           
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.Activity1)
            .WithMany(f => f.Predecessors)
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.Activity1_ID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>().
             HasRequired(f => f.Activity2)
            .WithMany(f => f.Successors)
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.Activity2_ID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Shyju, Thanks for the response. Your answer was basically the same as my code but gave me a good hint on where to search. I only showed a very simplified classes here. In my actual activity class I also had two readonly properties which also return a list of relationships. Those two properties both return a filtered list of the relationships and are evaluated in code and were not meant to be mapped to the database. By adding the     [NotMapped] attribute to those properties the issue was solved. Thanx again!

Comment: I just had a similar problem with EF Core where, when trying to implement a minimalistic translation service, I had 2 "Translation" navigation properties to "Word". EF created the foreign key columns due to the different property names, so setting the foreign keys manually to the existing ones did the trick.